# Laravel 5.5 How to get eloquent relationship count?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, eager-loading, eloquent-relationship

I have three tables as define below

User

- id
- name

Post

- id
- text
- user_id

Comments

- id
- text
- post_id

This is User model User.php

```
class User
{
     public function post()
    {
       return $this->hasMany(Post::class);
    }   
}
```

This is my post model Post.php

```
    class Post
    {
       public function comments()
       {
          return $this->hasMany(Comment::class);
       }   
   }
```

Issue:

> I want to display no.of comments per user using eloquent eager loading.

Can anyone help me with that? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may define a new `hasManyThrough` relationship ([docs](https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent-relationships#has-many-through)) for user's comments:

```php
class User
{
    public function comments()
    {
        return $this->hasManyThrough(
            'App\Comment',
            'App\Post',
            'user_id', // Foreign key on posts table...
            'post_id', // Foreign key on comments table...
            'id', // Local key on users table...
            'id' // Local key on posts table...
        );
    }
}
```

Now you can count each user's comments ([Laravel docs](https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent-relationships#counting-related-models)):

```php
$users = App\User::withCount('comments')->get();

foreach ($users as $user) {
    echo $user->comments_count;
}
```